# How should I proceed with the proof concerning the trichotomy of reals?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am going through Analysis I by Terence Tao and am currently stuck at proving this proposition, which is as follows:

> Proposition 5.4.4 (Basic properties of positive reals). For every real number $x$, exactly one of the following three statements is true: (a) $x$ is zero; (b) $x$  is positive; (c) $x$  is negative.

How, I have proceeded so far:

If suppose $x$ is $0$,then the claim easily follows, therefore suppose it isn't then it must be bounded away from zero. If $x=LIM_{n\to \infty}a_n$, this must then mean that $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals and that there exists a positive rational $c$ such that $|a_n|\gt c$ for all natural $n$. But since $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence then there must be a natural $N$ such that $|a_j-a_k|\leq \frac{c}{2}$, for all $j,k\geq N$.

As I can visualise this then means the sequence will become positive or negative thereafter. But how can I continue after this? What arguments should I put forth?

---

As for the book that I am following the real numbers are defined using formal limits (hence $LIM$ and not $\lim$). The author does state that formal limits will eventually be superceded by the actual limits but I haven't reached upto that point so I'm avoiding to use the notation for the same. For now consider a real number to be any object of form $LIM_{n\to \infty}a_n$ where $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals and two reals are equal if and only if their respective sequences are equivalent.

Comment: Do you know about the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes I do know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.

The key idea you are missing is to focus on the subsequence $a_N,a_{N+1},a_{N+2}$, ..., and in particular to focus on the first element of that subsequence. You know that $|a_N| > c$, and so you can break the proof into two cases.

Case 1: $a_N > c$. In this case, you have everything you need to prove that $a_n > c/2$ for all $n \ge N$.

Case 2: $a_N < -c$. And in this case, you have everything you need to prove that $a_n < -c/2$ for all $n \ge N$.